# Sum of Combimations

Tags: summation

The cardinality of a power set of $n$ elements is given by: $2^n$.
The cardinality of the power set can be given by the sum of the cardinality of the sets which make up the power set. I.e the sum of the combinations of $n$ from $0$ to $n$.

$2^n$ = $ \sum^n _{i=0}nCi$

I tried to derive this myself, but failed. Can I get an easy to understand derivation of the formula?

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $A$ of $n\geq1$ elements and an $i\in[0\>..\>n]$ there are exactly ${n\choose i}$ ways to pick an $i$-element subset of $A$. It follows that there are 
$$\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}=\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}1^{n-i}\>1^i=(1+1)^n=2^n$$
different subsets of $A$, i.e. $\bigl|{\cal P}(A)\bigr|=2^n$.

In your question you are speaking about the "sum of the cardinalities" of all these subsets (call it  $N$), which is something different. One arrives at this sum by the following argument: Any given element $k\in A$ occurs in $2^{n-1}$ subsets of $A$. It is therefore counted $2^{n-1}$ times when we are building up $N$. It follows that
$$N=n\cdot 2^{n-1}\ .$$